# C++ templates in class

Tags: c++, templates

I have some class, which have some methods. I want to use template only for one method, not for all class. Can I do like this?

```
class Test {
  private:
    int i;
  public:
    Test(int i);
    int getVal();
    void setVal(int i);

    template <class Type>
    int testTemplate(Type val);
};
```

Comment: It should be legal. Compile and run it, then you can tell us if you can do it like that :)

Comment: Its work) But I want to know is this solution bad or no?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly legal and used in many cases, like conversion function templates. See this for more info: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template

Just please remember to write this function definition either inline or at least in the same file, otherwise it can not compile.
Additionally, if there's no call to this function in your project, it won't be generated, so that saves you some space.

Comment: It's actually possible to write templated functions in a separate file with a little trickery. Rather than the more common `#include foo.h` at the top of the cpp file, you can `#include foo.cpp` at the bottom of the header file.

Comment: @swinefish: Don't include **cpp**, renamethe file to be .hxx or .inl.

Comment: At my previous institution we used .imp (for implementation) but you're correct.

Comment: Which file does I have to rename?

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, that code it perfectly legal. It should compile and work (if correctly implemented). As to whether it's a good solution, it's fine. If that is the only function that you need templated, then only do that one. If you make the whole class a templated class it can add some extra overhead that you don't need. So as you have done, just have that one function.

Answer (score 0):

It is legal. Whether you declare the template outside or inside the class, just use the type defined in the template only in the method and that will make the function template being used for the only method you need.